# Save imports in file and use it in LWC js

Tags: lightning-web-components, import

Hello everybody I am working in different LWC forms that contains comboboxes that are used in those different LWC forms.
In my javascript file I have repeated the same field imports and I do not want to import them again.

```
import ITEM1_API_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.QX_Item1__c';
```

I was thinking of creating a file where I can storage all of the imports and import only once the file that contain all of those imports and use in my js file.

Does anybody know how to do it? Or even if that is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via modules.

1. Create a new LWC component for your fields.
2. Add all imports to .js file.

```js
// myFields.js
import ITEM1_API_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.QX_Item1__c';
import ITEM2_API_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.QX_Item2__c';

const FIELDS = {
    ITEM1_API_FIELD,
    ITEM2_API_FIELD
};

export { FIELDS };
```

3. Import FIELDS in other LWC components.

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { FIELDS } from "c/myFields";

export default class Demo extends LightningElement {}
```

Resources:

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_share_code
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/lightning-web-components-service-components

Comment: +1 You can also use `export { default as NAME } from '@salesforce/schema/object.field';` which saves the need for the const and extra export. You can also import all values from a module at once, giving the same general accessibility as your solution. I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can make the code more efficient by way of exporting the fields directly:

```
 // fields.js
 export { default as ITEM1_API_FIELD } from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.QX_Item1__c';
 export { default as ITEM2_API_FIELD } from '@salesforce/schema/SObject.QX_Item2__c';
```

And for easier importing, you can use:

```
// myComponent.js
import * as FIELDS from 'c/fields';
```

Which you can then use as:

```
getValue(record, FIELDS.ITEM1_API_FIELD);
```